# How do I change the color of the selected time of <input matInput type="time" step="1" /> time picker?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am using the code below as a time picker in an angular 9 application. I need to change the selected time's color (bright blue). how can I achieve this?

```html
<input matInput type="time" step="1" value]="value"/>
```

[image]

Comment: You can't. Styling for inputs is set by the browser. Though in Chrome 91 you can enable a flag for [accent-color](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-91/#accent-color) which you can use to change the default color of (some) inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find a solution to change to custom color but
put `<meta name="color-scheme" content="dark light">` in `index.html` would do the trick for dark mode